# Weird answers showing up in C programming

Tags: c

I am new to programming and have just started C programming. However, I got a weird answer when I tried this simple piece of code.

```
char str[1000], ch;
int i, frequency;

printf(" Enter a string: ");
gets(str);

printf(" Enter the character you want to find the frequency of: ");
scanf(" %c", &ch);

for (i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++){
   if ( ch == str[i]){
     ++frequency;
 }
}
printf(" The frequency of %c is %d", ch, frequency);
return 0;
```

The answer I got was this:

`Enter a string: This website is awesome`

`Enter the character you want to find the frequency of: e`

```
The frequency of e is 12
```

Is there a problem with my compiler? I was trying this piece of code from an online source, so it should work, right? So it should be 4 right?

Comment: please pot the code

Comment: You should paste code here. Not links and definitely not pictures or links to pictures.

Comment: Please copy-paste the code and error message as text instead of making screenshots. That way people can run the code and look for the error message online.

Comment: 'piece of code from an online source, so it should work, right?' LOL!  No.  All kinds of strage code are posted online, some of it good.

Comment: It will probably become better when you initialize `frequency` before using it.

Comment: No.... code as text!   Not links, not pics..  Text!

Comment: Code I get from other people, I don't trust too much. They could've made errors. Code I wrote myself, I don't trust too much. From my experience I know, I make errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialised `frequency`. What does it start as, before you start adding to it. Answer: nobody knows, but it looks like it was `8` in your example.

Because you never set it, it's whatever the memory was last used for. You really should set it to `0` before you use the value.

Comment: Oh, got it. Found my mistake. Thank you! Appreciate it a lot

Comment: @Ray If this solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer. You can do so by clicking the tick under the voting buttons so that it turns green. (Usually, upvoting an answer is the way to say "thank you" on Stack Overflow, but you don't have enough reputation points to do so.)

Comment: Ohh, thank you for the guidance. I'm new here, but would love to learn from you peeps!

Comment: @Ray If you have another question, feel free to post a comment on this answer linking to it. That's not usual procedure, but I'd like to help you get used to the site (it's an incredible resource and you'll need to know how to use it if you're planning to go into the software development field as a job).